# Get the list of coordinates of all markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinates

I am trying to make a web map in which I can add a marker on map and at the same time get the lat lon coordinates of all markers to be saved on my database later on. I came up with this function to do that:

```
function newMarker(e) {
  var new_mark = L.marker()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .addTo(map_4562f93a48a3459d95c4d292f52b5adc);
  new_mark.dragging.enable();
  new_mark.on("dblclick", function(e) {
    map_4562f93a48a3459d95c4d292f52b5adc.removeLayer(e.target);
  });

  var latlngs = [];
  var lat = e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4),
    lng = e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4),
    mark_latlon = new_mark.getLatLng();

  map_4562f93a48a3459d95c4d292f52b5adc.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    latlngs.push(mark_latlon);
    console.log(latlngs);
  });

  new_mark.bindPopup("Waypoint");
}

map_4562f93a48a3459d95c4d292f52b5adc.on("click", newMarker);
```

The problem with this code is that it just adds the coordinates of the last marker every time a marker is created by clicking. I want all the coordinates to be appended to *latlongs* Array. And if possible I want to it to be updated when deleted or dragged. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do - on very new marker, it's creating a new empty array, iterating through every layer in the map (including things that are nor markers), and adding the latlng of the newly added marker (`mark_latlon`) to the array, instead of the coords of the layer it's iterating through (that would be `layer.getLatLng()` for [`L.Marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker-getlatlng)s)